# Why javascript function in the body takes precedence over function in the head?

Tags: javascript, function, execution

I am trying to understand the order of execution in javascript. Why is it that foo in the body has priority over foo in the head. Is it not the foo in the head that is compiled first?

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Hello</title>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function foo() {
      greeting = "hello from the head";
      alert(greeting);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="clickMe" onclick="foo()">Click me</div>
  <script>
    function foo() {
      greeting = "hello from the body";
      alert(greeting);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Later function declarations overwrite older function declarations. The older function can still be called *before the newer function has been declared*:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function foo() {
    greeting = "hello from the head";
    alert(greeting);
  }
  foo();
</script>
<div id="clickMe" onclick="foo()">Click me</div>
<script>
  function foo() {
    greeting = "hello from the body";
    alert(greeting);
  }
</script>
```

but once the lower script tag runs, the function name is reassigned. It might make more sense if you look at it like this, with each function reassigning `window.foo`:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.foo = function foo() {
    greeting = "hello from the head";
    alert(greeting);
  }
</script>
<div id="clickMe" onclick="window.foo()">Click me</div>
<script>
  window.foo = function foo() {
    greeting = "hello from the body";
    alert(greeting);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Javascript is not interpreted. It has a runtime compiler.

Answer (score 2):

It's no different than declaring the same function twice

```js
function foo() {
  console.log("first");
}

function foo() {
  console.log("second");
}

foo();  // prints "second"
```

Which is on some level no different than this

```
let bar;
bar = 1;
bar = 2;
```

`bar` is now `2`.

You can avoid this by using a different syntax

```js
const foo = () => {
  console.log("first");
};

const foo = () => {
  console.log("second");
};
```

In which case you'll get an error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'foo' has already been declared
```

and seems to work even across scripts

```html
<script>
const foo = () => {
  console.log("first");
};
</script>
<script>
const foo = () => {
  console.log("second");
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is call Shadowing.

JS compiler hoists functions as they are found in the script. The later ones overwrite the earlier encounters with the same name.

```
function foo() {
   console.log('Foo early');
}

function foo() {
   console.log('Foo late');
}

foo();    //Foo leate
```

Comment: This is not shadowing. The difference is that shadowing implies there is still a reference to the original definition.

Comment: How can shadowing have a reference to the original definition? Can you give an example?

Comment: `var array = []; array.map = () => {}; array.map(); /* returns undefined */ delete array.map; array.map(() => {}); /* returns array */` This uses the prototype chain to _shadow_ the definition of `map()`. Similar examples exist when using DOM element attributes and properties with the same name like `value` on `HTMLInputElement`.

Comment: That is property shadowing. While it is true, it doesn't make the OPs case not shadowing. The later declarations shadows the earlier hoisted function.

Comment: "Property shadowing", whatever you prefer to call it, still exists with top-level function declarations, which are simply an own property of `window`. For example `function addEventListener () {}` would shadow `window.addEventListener` since it's not an own property of `window`, but `function prompt () {}` would overwrite `window.prompt` since it _is_ an own property of `window`

Comment: Again, this doesn't make OPs case not shadowing.

Comment: I am confused now, so is it call shadowing or not :)

Comment: In general programming, if the visibility of a variable/function/object/property etc is hidden by another of the same name, such instance is called shadowing. So is yours.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's just because the one in the body is the last function it reads, so it just sticks with it.

Remember the HTML Document is read from top to bottom, so if you have two instances of the same function, it will actually keep the one closest to the end of the document